# Move a player n units closer to point X

Tags: javascript, math, game-physics

I have a player, which looks like this:

```
{
   x: [could be any integer],
   y: [could be any integer],
   facing: {
      x: [could be any integer],
      y: [could be any integer]
   }
}
```

Assuming the player is at (`player.x`, `player.y`), and the player is facing in the direction of the mouse, which is at (`player.facing.x`, `player.facing.y`), what is a formula that I could use to move the player n units in the direction of the mouse?

Here is what I've tried so far, but it always results in `null`:

```
var facingDistance = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(game.players[i].facing.x, 2) - Math.pow(game.players[i].x, 2));

game.players[i].x += (game.players[i].speed/facingDistance) *
(game.players[i].x - game.players[i].facing.x);

game.players[i].y += (game.players[i].speed/facingDistance) *
(game.players[i].y - game.players[i].facing.y);
```

Comment: x and y of mouse should be enough to get the direction of mouse

Comment: @sumeetkumar but I cant figure out how. if you think you have an idea, could you please share it with me? I am stumped on this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// prefetch player object for cleaner code
var plr = game.players[i];

// normalized player direction
var facingDX = plr.facing.x - plr.x;
var facingDY = plr.facing.y - plr.y;
var facingLen = Math.sqrt(facingDX * facingDX + facingDY * facingDY);
facingDX /= facingLen;
facingDY /= facingLen;

// add n times this to position + round to integer coordinates
plr.x = Math.round(plr.x + facingDX * n);
plr.y = Math.round(plr.y + facingDY * n);
```

Comment: for some reason, this is still returning `null` every time.

Comment: @eeze what part of it is returning `null`? The end position or the player? Show the full code since the problem might be elsewhere.

Comment: sorry, your code was fine. it was a problem with mine XD

Comment: @eeze haha, no problem.